# Is it grammatically wrong if we say 'I have been unable too' and 'I have not been able either'?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, sentence, sentence-patterns

So, If the context is like this:

Person 1: Hey, due to a black out in my region, I have not been able to turn on my TV. So, I missed some parts of the show.

Person 2: What a coincidence! I have not been able to either.

I was wondering if putting either at the end of the sentence caused any grammatical error.

Comment: Person 2 would've said _I haven't been able to, either_. Not contracting auxiliaries is a mark of reading aloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding *either* is not an error at all. However, Person 2 would be more likely to say "I haven't either" without any need to repeat *be able to.*

Comment: Sorry for this last side question.What if the Person 2 says: 'I have been unable to either' if the dialogue of Person 1 was 'I have been unable to turn on my TV'. Is it an error now?

Comment: Yes, that's an error. If there isn't a negative in the sentence we don't use _either_ (even though _to be unable_ has a negative meaning). It would sound very stiff and formal, but Person 2 would have to say "I have been unable to as well" or "I, too have been unable to."

Comment: The problem is I know it is an error. But please don't get me wrong I am still skeptical if we say it has a grammatical error. Because there is no book or explanation that says we cannot use either here.

Comment: How about [this?](https://site.uit.no/english/grammar/either-and-neither/) "Either is combined with a negative verb - _John did not either_." Even though _be unable to_ has a negative meaning, because the sentence doesn't contain _not_ we can't use _either_.

Comment: I feel so dumb. I read the article before. And, it says we can use it with negative verbs. I think of it as a loophole.